# How do I get a Donut Chart in R?

Tags: r, donut-chart

I try to draw a Donut Chart with a tutorial code but I get an error I cannot explain.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
```

## Calculate and cumulate percentages

```
df$fraction = df$freq / sum(df$freq)
df$ymax = cumsum(df$fraction)
df$ymin = c(0, head(df$ymax, n=-1))
```

## Draw chart

```
ggplot(df, aes(ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, xmax=4, xmin=3, fill=category)) +
  geom_rect() +
  coord_polar(theta="y") + 
  xlim(c(2, 4))
```

I get this error:

> Error in `geom_rect()`:
> ! Problem while computing aesthetics.
> ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
> Caused by error in `FUN()`:
> ! object 'category' not found
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: The error suggests that you don't have a `category` variable in the dataframe.

Comment: From the image of your dataset: Perhaps you want `fill=word`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please **don't ever create pie or donut plots**   They are the most useless and uninformative of almost any plot type known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change fill=category to fill=word, then it works:

```
df <- data.frame (word  = c("dolor", "amet", "diam", "ipsum", "lorem", "sed", "sit", "accusam", "aliquyam", "clita"),freq = c(48,24,24,24,24,24,24,12,12,12))

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df$fraction = df$freq / sum(df$freq)
df$ymax = cumsum(df$fraction)
df$ymin = c(0, head(df$ymax, n=-1))

ggplot(df, aes(ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, xmax=4, xmin=3, 
fill=word)) +
geom_rect() +
coord_polar(theta="y") + 
xlim(c(2, 4))
```